# Using geometrical sum to infinity to do long division?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-fractions

I was doing the partial fraction of $\frac{1}{x^6}(\frac{x-2}{x^2+1})$. By using long division I get:
$$\frac{1}{x^6}(\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}) = \frac{1}{x^6}\left [ -2 + x  + 2x^2 -x^3 -2x^4 + x^5+\frac{2x^6-x^7}{1+x^2} \right ]$$

$$\\\frac{1}{x^6}(\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}) = \left [ \frac{-2}{x^6} + \frac{1}{x^5}  + \frac{2x}{x^4} -\frac{1}{x^3} -\frac{2}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x}+\frac{2-x}{1+x^2} \right ]
$$

I noticed that $\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}$ looks like a geometrical sum to infinity $\frac{a}{1-r}$ with **$r = -x^2$** and $a = x - 2$. So:

$$\frac{1}{x^6}\frac{x-2}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{x^6}\left [(x-2)-x^2(x-2)+x^4(x-2)-\frac{x^6(x-2)}{x^2+1}\right ]$$

$$= \left [ \frac{-2}{x^6} + \frac{1}{x^5}  + \frac{2x}{x^4} -\frac{1}{x^3} -\frac{2}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x}+\frac{2-x}{1+x^2} \right ]$$

Which yield the same result, I know that $|r| = |-x^2| < 1$ has to be true for the convergence. But the question obviously didn't state that.
So my question is can I use this way to do replace the process of long division which is slower. Is it even legal to do this? And will this always be true?

Comment: yes, this makes sense. it is a common trick in generating functions, for example

Comment: Could you explain in detail why it makes sense, even thought the range of $-x^2$ is not necessary in 1?

Comment: aren't you only using a finish piece of the expansion?

Comment: What does "finish piece of the expansion"  means?

Comment: typo, "finite piece of the expansion"